# TinyMCE: How to manually show add/edit Link window?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'd like to assign a custom shortcut key (CTRL+K) to my TinyMCE editor so that, when pressed, the "Add/Edit Link" window will open. (Toolbar button = "link")

I know I need to use the `addShortcut` method in `setup()` (during init) to assign the key, but I can't figure out what command I should use:

```
setup : function(editor)
{
    editor.addShortcut('ctrl+k', 'Show Link Window', 'some_command_goes_here');
},
```

No amount of Googling has led me to a list of editor commands that I can invoke like this. If any of you guys have any ideas, that would be fantastic.

Thanks!

(I'm using TinyMCE 3, not 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the command is: **mceLink**

Luckily I stumbled across [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963389/tinymce-custom-link-button-command-with-jquery), because I still can't find this referenced anywhere in TinyMCE's documentation...